# C# WPF Splash Screen (Window) on Secondary Thread: Trying to understand why this works?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a C# WPF app. I have two windows (Main & Splash). Once started the processes of the main deserialzie various large chunks of data, language files, and saved dictionaries (on a custom converter), which all run from async tasks. It takes about 1500ms to fully load the main window and allow user interaction. (It was 3000ms before I set up the async tasks).

Due to this I wanted a splash screen with a simple animation just so the user can see something is happening. It's a basic window with a couple of text blocks and a Progress control, which has an animation through the style:

```
<ProgressBar Grid.Row="2"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Style="{DynamicResource ProgressBarStyle}"
             IsIndeterminate="True"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ProgressBarIndeterminate"
            RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Animation"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                              Value="0.25" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1"
                              Value="0.25" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2"
                              Value="0.25" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Animation"
                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransformOrigin)">
        <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                             Value="-0.5,0.5" />
        <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1"
                             Value="0.5,0.5" />
        <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2"
                             Value="1.5,0.5" />
    </PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

I originally had the splash and main windows loading using the App OnStartUp override like this:

```
static readonly Mutex Mute = new(true, @"Global\{3A59A840-AD95-40DB-9B86-5045213B23E0}");

protected override void OnStartup (StartupEventArgs e) {

    if (Mute.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true)) {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        Windows.SplashWindow Splsh = new();
        MainWindow = Splsh;
        Splsh.Show();

        Task.Run(() => {
            Task.Delay(250).Wait();
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                Windows.MainWindow Main = new();
                MainWindow = Main;
                Main.Show();
                Splsh.Close();
            });
        });

        Mute.ReleaseMutex();
    }
    else {
        Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

As I built more and more deserializing and data calculations into the initial startup (as you might have guessed) the animation on the splash screen froze as all of the processing was occurring.

After trying various methods which did not resolve my issue - async Tasks, Dispatcher.Invoke, Dispatcher.BeginInvoke etc - I came to the conclusion I would need to look at starting a secondary thread to handle the Splash while Main did it's thing.

After much reading and a few false starts, I ended up with this:

```
static readonly Mutex Mute = new(true, @"Global\{3A59A840-AD95-40DB-9B86-5045213B23E0}");

protected override void OnStartup (StartupEventArgs e) {
    if (Mute.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true)) {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        Mute.ReleaseMutex();
        ThreadStart threadStart = new(() => {
            Windows.SplashWindow splash = new();
            splash.Show();
            DispatcherFrame frame = new();
            Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrames), frame);
            Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
        });
        Thread thread = new(threadStart);
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
        Windows.MainWindow main = new();
        main.Show();
        main.Activate();
    }
    else {
        Current.Shutdown();
    }
}

static object ExitFrames (object frame) { ((DispatcherFrame)frame).Continue = false; return null!; }
```

This works exactly how I want it to - the splash shows and is animated, about 1500ms later the Main window appears and the Splash disappears - BUT there are a few things I don't quite understand and was hoping someone could explain.

1. Why does the Splash not show if I don't have the push frame?
2. Why does the Splash close without being told to do so?
3. Why does the Splash thread end without being cancelled? (Guessing those two are linked)
4. Why do I have to Activate the Main window to bring it to the front of any other open apps, when I didn't have to before?
5. If I put in a line to close the Splash I get an error about "not the thread that created it". Is there a way to correct that so I can close/dispose of the Splash and bring it under my control rather than whatever is currently doing it (being the answers of 1 - 3) ?
6. Most importantly: Is what I have done thread-safe?

Any help much appreciated.Thanks.

EDIT: I think I have got a better idea of what is happening:

1 - 3 looks to be a function of GC. While the secondary thread is started, the ThreadStart it isn't triggered until MainWindow is initialized. Once initialization is complete the thread shutsdown. I'm not entirely sure why, as changing IsBackground to false, or priority doesn't seem to alter the behaviour.

5 is also solved with the addition of splash.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, splash.Close) after main.Show is called.

Which leaves me 4 & 6. Any pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not the WPF guy, but 2 + 3 are probably because you marked the thread as background and I think _main.Show()_ is blocking till it did its stuff. Afterwards the method will be left and the reference to the splash thread is gone, which bring GC into play to clean up the thread, which closes your window.

Comment: @Oliver GC was my guess too. I've not used explicit multi-threading like this before, so I'm just trying to wrap my head around it. I have worked out the answer to 5 though, being: 'splash.Dispatcher.Invoke(splash.Close)', so that's something.

Comment: Have you seen [How to add a splashscreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-wpf-application?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)? While it lacks animations, it seem far simpler and likely more reliable as well.

Comment: @JonasH Yeah, but the best way to learn is to try new things :D

Comment: You can't run UI elements on a non-UI thread. Push all data operations to a background, but only use one thread for all UI.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fair bit of guesswork, so take everything with a fair grain of salt. I hope someone will correct me if I'm making any fundamental mistakes.

> Why does the Splash not show if I don't have the push frame?

Since `.Show()` is used instead of `.ShowDialog()`, the thread will continue execution of the method. If you do not enter a message loop the thread will exit, and the window will either close, or more likely, just not show at all.

> Why does the Splash close without being told to do so?

You are scheduling `ExitFrames` to run on the UI thread, and it can only do so once the main window has loaded. This exists the message loop started by `PushFrame`.

> Why does the Splash thread end without being cancelled? (Guessing those two are linked)

Once the message loop exits the thread will reach the end of its method, and exit naturally.

> Why do I have to Activate the Main window to bring it to the front of any other open apps, when I didn't have to before?

Likely because windows activates the first window an application displays, i.e. your splash screen. If you show any other windows that are not childs of this, they may pop up behind other windows.

> If I put in a line to close the Splash I get an error about "not the thread that created it". Is there a way to correct that so I can close/dispose of the Splash and bring it under my control rather than whatever is currently doing it (being the answers of 1 - 3)

You need to send a message to the UI thread that owns the window to run the code to close it. The slash screen window should have a `Dispatcher`-object you can use to send messages or request it to run code.

> Most importantly: Is what I have done thread-safe?

I think so, but it is not how I would have done it.

I would instead suggest to call `.ShowDialog()` to show the splash screen, and add a run `splash.Dispatcher(splash.Close)` from the main UI thread when it has completed loading. Or have the splash screen register an event handler on `main.Loaded`, or some other suitable event that runs the same `Dispatcher(Close)`-code.

Or just use a [static splash screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-wpf-application?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)